# How is a long timer implemented?

Tags: timer

Given the following constraints:

- ~20% accuracy or better
- Vcc=5V
- Input is the falling edge of a TTL signal
- Output can be TTL or the input to a Schmitt trigger
- Time between 1-60min adjustable via pot or similar

I'm considering my options for a very simple timer. RC in this case is not very practical due to the components needed - for my first iteration, where a 2200uF cap needed to discharge to 1V, the resistance required was 1MΩ. 1M is too uncomfortably close to the input impedance of the next stage (5M), so I have leakage concerns with that low current; and caps in that range start to get expensive.

My preference is simplicity and low cost, so if I can pull this off without the use of an MCU or RTC that's what I'd prefer; but they're not out of the question.

Comment: You don't need to get the most expensive µC on the market... the [cheapest PIC](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/40001239F.pdf) µC would solve your problem graciously and probably be your cheapest bet. Olin has demonstrated several times through other answers that it is a formidable item. - There is an internal timer, but you can easily extend it further by counting other registers, you can probably count until the end of the universe with the 16 or 24 bytes of ram.

Comment: Tiny: PIC12 family.  It needs a tiny bit of software.  If you want an all-hardware solution, check out the CD4060.  Many old-time kitchen timers use that chip - you can get to 60 minutes with it.

Comment: @DwayneReid I love the idea of using a CD4060 (the fact that the datasheet looks like a photocopy from the 1970s not being the least of my reasons). So - RC with a pot, going to the 4060 as a divider. I'll hack together a circuit diagram and then edit my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bottom line is for a time delay this long you need an arrangement based around a counter driven by an oscillator. Trying to do the delay in a single analog circuit just requires unreasonably high R and C values.

In days gone by you would build a oscillator with something like a 555 and then use counter chips (cascaded if necessary) for the counting. Nowadays though the cheapest option is almost certainly a small 8 pin micro controller with internal oscillator.

Comment: There's always the CMOS **7**555, which allows to build both ultra-fast and ultra-slow timers without additional dividers.

Comment: It's not impossible, but you still have a bulky and expensive capacitor and a circuit that is sensitive to leakage.

Comment: Yeah.. for less money than a 7555, I've found an 8-pin MCU that will do the timing with an internal oscillator, plus replace a few other components in the meantime. So it's the clear winner (although seeing the alternatives is a learning experience).